# Number of critical points of the sum of a function and a linear function

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question. Let $f(x)$ be a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, with $M$ critical points $(x^{(1)}, \dots, x^{(M)})$ that solve $\nabla f (x) = 0$. We now sum to $f$ a linear function (geometrically, an hyperplane) $h(x) = \sum_i k_i x_i$, and we call the sum $g(x) = f(x) + h(x)$.

Can we say something about the critical points of $g(x)$ in terms of the critical points of $f(x)$? My guess is that $g(x)$ still has $M$ critical points $\forall \,(f(x), h(x))$, but I could not find a simple proof or a simple counter example. Of course, the positions of the critical points is affected by $h(x)$.

**EDIT**: Now I understand that my guess is not true for general $f$. It seems that the provided counterexamples are based on one of these $2$ ingredients:

- The expansion of $f$ around a critical point has no $2^{nd}$ order term;
- The gradient of $f$ cannot take arbitrary values.

Is it possible to find a counterexample that does not rely on these $2$ ingredients? Maybe my guess is true for a limited class of $f$s

**EDIT 2**: As pointed out in one of the comments, the function $f(x) = x^3 + \epsilon x$ does not have a high order critical point for $\epsilon \neq 0$, but still when you add a linear function $h$ the number of its critical points can change.

The question now is: is there a class of $f$s for which my guess is true?

For example, let's say we consider functions that are a sum of a convex function and a quadratic form, and then we add $h(x)$: is the number of critical points of $f$ and $g$ always the same in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of critical points of $g$ can be less than, equal to, or larger than the number of critical points of $f$.

Example in one dimension: $f(x) = x^3$ has exactly one critical point. $g(x) = x^3+ ax$ has no critical points if $a> 0$, one critical point if $a=0$, and two critical points if $a< 0$.

Another example: $f(x) = \sin(x)$ has infinitely many critical points, but $f(x) +2x$ has no critical points at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think these counterexamples are insightful. I edited the question to make it less trivial: can one find other counterexamples that do not rely on either high order critical points or bounded gradients?

Comment: If you replace $x^3$ by $x^3 + \epsilon x$ or $\sin(x) $ by $\sin(x)+ \epsilon x$ then the same observation holds, but the second derivative is no longer zero at the critical points of $f$.

Comment: You have convinced me with $x^3 + \epsilon x$, but $sin(x) + \epsilon x$ still has bounded gradient -- in the sense that the gradient cannot take arbitrary positive and negative values

Comment: @G.Carugno: We have tried to answer your question, but I refuse to update my answer repeatedly after the question has changed. My suggestion would be that you post a follow-up question instead.

Comment: Sure, sorry. Thanks nonetheless

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example: $f(x,y) = \frac 13(x^3+y^3)$, $h(x,y)=x-y$. Although $f(x,y)$ has one critical point, $g(x,y)=f(x,y)+h(x,y)$ does not have critical points.

Comment: Great counterexample, thanks. I edited the question to make it less trivial: can one find other counterexamples that do not rely on either high order critical points or bounded gradients?